# What is the plane on the Home Bush Bay Funsaver EP cover?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]
Found this CD I had in 1997 and just bought it again as it got lost.

There is an aircraft which I cannot identify:

- the sticker on the propeller leads to a propeller manifacturer called Avia
- guess its a double engine plane with retractable landing gears
- the picture on the CDs are invertet so I inverted the colors
- guess it's a combustion engine, not a jet
- the vent slots are pretty similar to Zlin planes but could not find a model which fits to the pictures

Solved: it's an **Let L-200 Morava**, thanks for your answers!

Comment: Is it possible you can adjust the first picture so that it is not upside down?

Comment: @RonBeyer I get the feeling the image is fine as it is and the engine was upside down in the original.

Comment: I was going to ask for album and artist, then I realized that it was on the CD label. Then I read "Home Bush" and thought "Is this Australian?" Then I looked at your user name. I get there. Eventually...

Comment: @FreeMan His user name says _Austrian_ pilot, not Australian. :)

Comment: By the way @AustrianPilot, I think maybe you mean to say "piston engine" rather than "combustion engine." Jet engines are also combustion engines.

Comment: Hey, @reirab, did I tell you about that time I hopped that Lauda Air flight from Perth to Melbourne? ;) Sigh...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I submit the Let L-200 Morava.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_L-200_Morava

Engine Nacelles:

[image: Engine Nacelles]
[image]

Nacelles and Nose Gear:

[image: Nacelles and Nose gear]

Nose gear Higher resolution:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was just going to suggest a hint that AVIA is a Czech company. And someone has already traced the whole thing down!

Comment: I like how convenient this plane is.  When parking in a hangar you can just ram it into the back wall and the front tire will stop you.  What a time saver!